# Spatialisation/diffusion of sound across 24 channels

Tags: techniques, tools, multichannel

I am looking for a tool/technique which would enable me spatialise diffenent sine waves across a (circular) 24-channel system in various speeds. This is not to be done live, but using playback of pre-recorded samples. Unfortunately I have no access to the system and have to prepare the materials using a minimal stereo setup. Is there a plugin or workflow which I could use for this? Any recommendations?

Ideally I would want something that would show me graphical representation of the different channels and allow me to design what will be heard on each channel and for how long, etc. I would then need to export each channel as a separate track.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you're looking after, but you can route each sample/vst/live instrument on different channels in any standard DAW mixer.

For example, you have 24 different sine waves samples:

1. Assign each one of the 24 sines on 24 different channels
2. Manualy pan each channel as you wish , until the resulting stereo sound fits your expectations

And additionally,

Insert on the Master Channel, a Sound Imager Plug-in (Ex:Izotope 5 Sound Imager) , wich gives you the ability to stereoize and give more space for the master output. 
(Optionally, you can insert this kind of plug-in on each individual channel, depending on your preferences).

But as I said, not knowing exactly what you're aiming for, this is all i can think of.

I hope it helps you somehow,
Alex

Note: For the Stereo Imager plug-in to work, the Sample(s) must be Stereo tracks.
[Check this out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4Aq0K05DPc)

Answer (score 0):

Check out REAPER. Its surround tool should be able to do exactly what you're after.

Fully functioning demo free from their site and if you like it, it's only $60 to buy!

Comment: Any chance to do this with Pro Tools, Logic or Live?

Comment: No idea sorry mate. I don't bother with them since finding REAPER!

Comment: Possible with all of the DAWs you mentioned!